# Subtract df1 from df2, df2 from df3 and so on from all data from folder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have a few data frames as CSV files in the folder.

example1_result.csv

example2_result.csv

example3_result.csv

example4_result.csv

example5_result.csv

My each data frame looks like following

```
    TestID   Result1  Result2  Result3
       0       0        5        1      
       1       1        0        4        
       2       2        1        2        
       3       3        0        0        
       4       4        3        0       
       5       5        0        1
```

I want to subtract example1_result.csv from example2_result.csv on the Result1, Result2, and Result3 columns, and save it as a new data frame as result1.csv. Then the similar subtraction operation on example2_result.csv from example3_result.csv, and so on.

I want to do it using python scripts. Please help me as I am a novice in python. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "subtract example1_result.csv from example2_result.csv"? Please provide more sample data and the expected output of the subtraction

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: [Pandas User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given CSVs that look like:

```
TestID,Result1,Result2,Result3
0,0,5,1
1,1,0,4
2,2,1,2
3,3,0,0
4,4,3,0
5,5,0,1
```

Doing:

```
files = ['example1_result.csv', 'example2_result.csv', 
         'example3_result.csv', 'example4_result.csv',
         'example5_result.csv']

dfs = []
for file in files:
    # index_col matters, since we don't want to subtract TestID from eachother~
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col='TestID')
    dfs.append(df)

num_dfs = len(dfs)
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    if i + 1 == num_dfs:
        break
    df.sub(dfs[i+1]).to_csv(f'result{i+1}.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv") 
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv") 
dfresult = pd.DataFrame()
dfresult["Result1"] = df2["Result1"] - df1["Result1"]  # do for all columns
dfresult.to_csv("result.csv")
```

Comment: This will take a long time to code. consider automation

Comment: I thought I would give syntax and the questioner would do the automation

Comment: Look at the other answer